# Use DataNucleus with Glassfish 3.x

Tags: glassfish-3, datanucleus

I'm having troubles with use of DataNucleus as an ORM framework on Glassfish AS. Actually I'm trying to use to connect to MongoDb. I expected problems here as everybody knows that nosql databases are not a part of standard, but I faced with a problem to use DataNucleus. That is what I did not expect. I'm not familiar with both DataNucleus and MongoDB and unfortunately I failed to find any relevant information on the WEB, so I decided moving step-by-step.

I've created a small commandline application that uses DataNucleus and MongoDB and built with Maven. The relevant code is below

persistece.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="just_test">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:/justtest"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.validateTables" value="false"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.validateConstraints" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The code for persisting an entity

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("just_test");

        // Create entity manager
        EntityManager em = null;
        String id;
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
            tx.begin();
            em.persist(testEntity);
            em.flush();
            tx.commit();
            id = testEntity.getId();
        } finally {
            if (null != em) {
                em.close();
            }
        }

        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            TestEntity testEntity = em.find(TestEntity.class, id);
            System.out.println(testEntity);
        } finally {
            if (null != em) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>[2.9.3, )</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.9, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>[2.9, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>[3.0, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>[3.0, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>[1.1-rev-1, )</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0b</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-m3</version>
            <configuration>
                <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

This code works fine.

Once I tried to deploy an application that uses the same code the first thing that happened is that GF was not able to find some classes. Those classes were in an .ear file though. I hade to put several classes to the GF_HOME/glassfish/domains//lib directory to make GF able to find the classes, but finally I ended up with an exception

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named just_test
```

It worth to mention that the org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl class is in the datanucleus-api-jpa file that I also put in the domain's lib directory.

I also tried doing it with CDI like the following

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "just_test")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void persist(TestEntity testEntity) {
    entityManager.persist(testEntity);
}
```

This apprach also was not successful. I got an Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

Any ideas or links to aticles and/or documentation would be appreciated. Thanks

Below is the dependencies list that I use for the application which I'm trying to deploy on Glassfish. All dependencies that have 'provided' scope I had to put into the lib directory in Glassfish

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
    <version>[2.9, )</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>[2.9, )</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>[3.0, )</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0, )</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
    <version>[3.0, )</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You seem to have JPA1 jar (javax.persistence) in the CLASSPATH alongside JPA2 jar (geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec). If I was you I'd decide which version of JPA I wanted to use before anything else. Obviously the version of DN used there fully implements JPA2

Comment: @DataNucleus thank you for your comment. This dependecy was there because I found an example for the JPA1 first and than modified the code to use JPA2. I removed unnecessary dependency, but it did not help. I'm having the same stacktrace. I also modified my post and put the whole dependencies list that I use fo GF.

Comment: you have JDO 2.2 for some reason when that version of DN implements JDO 3.0. Glassfish will have its own JPA.jar present somewhere so maybe it doesn't want another one or is getting confused. The fact is that "org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl" does fully implement javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider so its a class loading thing

Comment: It seems that it is class loading problem. The question is why.

Comment: I do not have to take any special steps for use Hibernate for instance. Can you suggest any documentation related to it? I looked here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/guides/jpa/tutorial.html, but have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I had to modify dependencies as shown below

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <datanucleus.version>3.1.3</datanucleus.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also had to put all jars that have 'provided' scope to the GF_HOME/glassfish/domains//lib directory. I have no clue why I had to do so. It would be nice to have an answer to this. Hope that could save time to someone who wants to use Datanucleus with Glassfish